# OmniAuth triggering validations

Tags: ruby, facebook, authentication, twitter, omniauth

I am using OmniAuth in an application that requires authentication.

I have 3 ways for users to authenticate:

1. Create an account on my site
2. Facebook via OmniAuth
3. Twitter via OmniAuth

For option 1 I have validations in the form of:

```
  validates_presence_of     :email, :role
  validates_presence_of     :password,                   :if => :password_required
  validates_presence_of     :password_confirmation,      :if => :password_required
  validates_length_of       :password, :within => 4..40, :if => :password_required
  validates_confirmation_of :password,                   :if => :password_required
  validates_length_of       :email,    :within => 3..100
  validates_uniqueness_of   :email,    :case_sensitive => false
  validates_format_of       :email,    :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
  validates_format_of       :role,     :with => /[A-Za-z]/
```

The problem is that when I allow a user to login via twitter/facebook for the first time an Account is created, the validations are triggered, and fail.

For example:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid - Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 4 characters), Password confirmation can't be blank:

This makes sense as OmniAuth created accounts will not be submitting a password but i'm not sure exactly how i should make my model aware of this and skip (specific?) validations.

If it's of any use, the full account.rb model is here: http://pastie.org/private/wzpftprrzfg42uifetfhpa

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I found a way around it but i think it's a hack.  I made an addition to this method (as shown in my pastie above).  http://pastie.org/2229023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to extract the condition into the **encrypt_password** method from here, this line seems incorrect:

```
  # Callbacks
  before_save :encrypt_password, :if => :password_required
```

can you also copy-paste stack trace please?